# Getting function args type annotation inference of callee function from calling function

Tags: typescript

I have found a few places where I need to pass a few common args to functions. I'm annotating them each time i.e. in each function.

But is there a way to prevent that? Shouldn't TypeScript automatically pick that up? My linter warns me of that if I don't annotate second time.

Below is an example

```
function getLayout(formGroup: IFormGroup, formState: SlideBase['formState'], slideCode: string, formErrors: SlideBase['formErrors']) {
   const field = getField(fields[i], formState, slideCode, formErrors);
}

function getField(field: IField, formState: SlideBase['formState'], slideCode: string, formErrors: SlideBase['formErrors']) {
    ...
}
```

Given the above, can I eliminate the args annotation in function `getField`?

Comment: What do you mean *"automatically pick that up"*. It can see what you're calling `getField` with, but it's not just going to assume that that's correct. If it just assumed you were right all of the time, what would the point of the types be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as function are stand alone elements of your program with own interfaces. TS cannot inference types from the caller, as you can call the same function in few places with different arguments, and which caller to choose then?

The function should define the contract, not the caller. Caller should fulfill it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an object containing the common parameters so you wouldn't have to declare all the parameters.

```
type CommonParameters = { formState: SlideBase['formState'], slideCode: string, formErrors: SlideBase['formErrors'] }
function getLayout(formGroup: IFormGroup, o: CommonParameters) {
   const field = getField(fields[i], o);
}

function getField(field: IField, o: CommonParameters) {

}
```

If you want to keep all the parameters around, you could declare a tuple type and destructure the parameters from the tuple type. That way the types of the parameters would not have to be repeated, but I am not sure this is a net improvement unless you have very many such declarations:

```
type CommonParameter = Parameters<(formState: SlideBase['formState'], slideCode: string, formErrors: SlideBase['formErrors']) => void>
function getLayout(formGroup: IFormGroup, ...[formState, slideCode, formErrors]: CommonParameter) {
   const field = getField(fields[i], formState, slideCode, formErrors);
}

function getField(field: IField, ...[formState, slideCode, formErrors]: CommonParameter) {

}
```

Note we use `Parameters` to create a tuple from a function signature in order to preserve parameter names in the functions.